# weksocket on production server with https

Tags: node.js, websocket

I followed this example here
https://socket.io/get-started/chat

I am now trying to run it on my production server, but I am hitting a wall

in my ssh connection I am doing node index.js
I have the "listening on*:3000" message

Then I am trying to access the index.html via my browser using

https://mywebsite/websocket/index.html
It seems that the index is finding the /socket.io/socket.io.js file so this part should be fine

But in the browser console I have this error
socket.io.js:7 POST https://mywebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MNnvCry 404 ()

I am on apache and I have https activated
In my ssh console I should see user connected, but I am not.

Answer (score 0):

I have used socketio for a production build and had a similar issue.

This was solved by adding the following code to the ssl conf file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:3000%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

I added it just before the closing virtualhost tag.

Comment: Hi Adian thank you for your reply, when I try to restart apache with your code, I have an error. code=exited, status1/FAILURE

I think my problem is due to the fact that I am unable to access the :3000 port other than with localhost

when I do in my terminal
curl http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js

I can see the file just fine

But then when I do ( in my regular chrome browser )

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
and then go to the page

I have this
http://mywebsite.com/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Even if I force the port
<script src="http://mywebsite.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

http://mywebsite.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT


I checked the port 3000 node is listening on it
the firewall is 3000/tcp allow anywhere 3000/tcp (v6) allow anywhere (v6)

Comment: can you post a screen shot of the code you're using please.

Comment: I had to change few thing on my apache configuration, now the http version is working, still trying to make the https work.

Here is the screenshot
https://imgur.com/a/lEPCBlq

Also I had to mask my path to the keys : )
But on my file it's the correct path and the files are accessibles